# Override elements Z-index

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap. My website has the following structure

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top" id="mainNav">>

        <div class="container">
           //stuff goes here
        </div>
</nav>
```

```
<section id="signup" class="signup-section">
   <div class="container">
        //stuff goes here
      <form class="form-inline d-flex">
         //stuff goes here
      </form>
   </div>

</section>
```

Then i have made the following z index changes on the navbar

```
 .container
    {
       position:relative;


      }

   .navbar
    {

     z-index:9;
     }


  .signup-section{

   z-index:1;

    }

   .form-inline{

    z-index:1;

    }
```

Yet the navbar is still below the signup-section / form-inline when i scroll dow

Comment: How are navbar and signup sections rendered. z-index is relative to the  element in the hierarchy that has z-index

Comment: You mean i must identify the parent element to which they belong. The element is:

               <body id="page-top">

Comment: I think my problem is that in my application, the same form that is inside the 2nd code snippet is then placed inside the navbar that you see in the 1st snippet(when user is logged in). So in the one instance the form must not have a higher z index that the navbar and in another instance it must